# deploy rails app digital ocean server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, digital-ocean

I am bit new to rails but somehow I manage to make an rails app.
Now I want to deploy it to Digital Ocean server.
All I got is

1- complete ruby on rails app

2- IP for digital ocean

3- Username

4- Password

can someone tell me steps to deploy it and which tools to use?

(I used fireFTP and Filezella for changing in some existing apps, but not sure that they are useful here or not)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, thats a good start as for what you have :) 
You need certain tools to deploy on production. Here is what you need apart from what you have to deploy a rails app not just on digital oceans but pretty much on any server.

1. Capistrano: A deployment tool [github repo](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano)
2. Nginx: A web server
3. Application server: `Unicorn/Puma/Passenger` - I use both unicorn and passenger
4. SSH access to you server
5. Mysql or any database of your choice to be setup on server
6. You should also use `rvm` to manage the rubies
7. Additionally, you might also want to manage your packages using chef

With the tools listed above and following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-capistrano-nginx-and-puma) link you should be able to deploy the app on digital ocean

I would recommend that you install everything manually so you get the hang of it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am following this tutorial and on 7th step.
But now when I put "cap production deploy:initial" in terminal it gives the following error

DEBUG [63cf0a07] Running [ -d ~/.rvm ] on 162.243.10.38
DEBUG [63cf0a07] Command: [ -d ~/.rvm ]
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
Net::SSH::Authentication::AgentError: agent could not sign data with requested identity

Tasks: TOP => rvm:hook
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Any idea about this?

Comment: You have add your private key to ssh agent. Use this command ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Comment: thanks man
I 'm done with it but now there is another issue, I put question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36797315/sprocketsfilenotfound-couldnt-find-file-adminlte-with-type-application-ja
 have a look please

Comment: Sure. Will try to help if I can 